# Error using hypperref after updating MiKTeX annd TeXStudio

Tags: miktex, koma-script, texstudio, compilation-error

Since I updated `MiKTeX 4.9` and `TeXstudio 4.5.2` (git 4.5.2) my code no longer compiles. Hyperref seems to be the problem, if it´s not in, it works.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, filecolor=cyan, urlcolor=cyan, bookmarksnumbered=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev, nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    
    \blindtext
    
\end{document}
```

The log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.5) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.5.17)  17 MAY 2023 16:38
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./texstudio_Uvjvvh.tex
(texstudio_Uvjvvh.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-05-11>
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/koma-script\scr
book.cls
Document Class: scrbook 2023/04/24 v3.40 KOMA-Script document class (book)

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/koma-script\scr
kbase.sty
Package: scrkbase 2023/04/24 v3.40 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent b
asics and keyval usage)

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/koma-script\scr
base.sty
Package: scrbase 2023/04/24 v3.40 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/koma-script\scr
lfile.sty
Package: scrlfile 2023/04/24 v3.40 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/koma-script\scr
lfile-hook.sty
Package: scrlfile-hook 2023/04/24 v3.40 KOMA-Script package (using LaTeX hooks)


(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/koma-script\scr
logo.sty
Package: scrlogo 2023/04/24 v3.40 KOMA-Script package (logo)
)))
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval
.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
Applying: [2021/05/01] Usage of raw or classic option list on input line 252.
Already applied: [0000/00/00] Usage of raw or classic option list on input line
 368.
))
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/koma-script\toc
basic.sty
Package: tocbasic 2023/04/24 v3.40 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
\scr@dte@tocline@numberwidth=\skip48
\scr@dte@tocline@numbox=\box51
)
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `toc'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `toc' on input line 135.
Class scrbook Info: File `scrsize11pt.clo' used instead of
(scrbook)           file `scrsize11.clo' to setup font sizes on input line 2671
.

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/koma-script\scr
size11pt.clo
File: scrsize11pt.clo 2023/04/24 v3.40 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt
)
)
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/koma-script\typ
earea.sty
Package: typearea 2023/04/24 v3.40 KOMA-Script package (type area)
\ta@bcor=\skip49
\ta@div=\count185
\ta@hblk=\skip50
\ta@vblk=\skip51
\ta@temp=\skip52
\footheight=\skip53
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 10
(typearea)             BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 418.25555pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -6%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 47.2316pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = -12.5192pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 595.80026pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -25.16531pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 17.0pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 20.40001pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 11.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 47.6pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 13.6pt
(typearea)              on input line 1798.
)
\c@part=\count186
\c@chapter=\count187
\c@section=\count188
\c@subsection=\count189
\c@subsubsection=\count190
\c@paragraph=\count191
\c@subparagraph=\count192
\scr@dte@chapter@maxnumwidth=\skip54
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\chapter on input line 5957.
\scr@dte@section@maxnumwidth=\skip55
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\section on input line 5968.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\section on input line 5968.
\scr@dte@part@maxnumwidth=\skip56
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=true'
(scrbook)           for `\part on input line 5977.
\scr@dte@subsection@maxnumwidth=\skip57
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subsection on input line 5987.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subsection on input line 5987.
\scr@dte@subsubsection@maxnumwidth=\skip58
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subsubsection on input line 5997.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subsubsection on input line 5997.
\scr@dte@paragraph@maxnumwidth=\skip59
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\paragraph on input line 6008.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\paragraph on input line 6008.
\scr@dte@subparagraph@maxnumwidth=\skip60
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subparagraph on input line 6018.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subparagraph on input line 6018.
\abovecaptionskip=\skip61
\belowcaptionskip=\skip62
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box52
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lof'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lof' on input line 7201.
\scr@dte@figure@maxnumwidth=\skip63
\c@figure=\count193
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lot'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lot' on input line 7218.
\scr@dte@table@maxnumwidth=\skip64
\c@table=\count194
Class scrbook Info: Redefining `\numberline' on input line 7389.
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/babel\babel.s
ty
Package: babel 2023/05/11 v3.89 The Babel package
\babel@savecnt=\count195
\U@D=\dimen141
\l@unhyphenated=\language79

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/babel\txtbabe
l.def)
\bbl@readstream=\read2
\bbl@dirlevel=\count196

*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/arabi\bblopts.c
fg
File: bblopts.cfg 2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of
 babel
)
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/babel-english\U
Kenglish.ldf
Language: UKenglish 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/babel-english\e
nglish.ldf
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
Package babel Info: Hyphen rules for 'canadian' set to \l@english
(babel)             (\language0). Reported on input line 102.
Package babel Info: Hyphen rules for 'australian' set to \l@ukenglish
(babel)             (\language73). Reported on input line 105.
Package babel Info: Hyphen rules for 'newzealand' set to \l@ukenglish
(babel)             (\language73). Reported on input line 108.
)))
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/babel/locale/
en\babel-ukenglish.tex
Package babel Info: Importing font and identification data for UKenglish
(babel)             from babel-en-GB.ini. Reported on input line 11.
)
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.st
y
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
)
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\inputenc.s
ty
Package: inputenc 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks17
\inpenc@posthook=\toks18
)
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/koma-script\scr
layer-scrpage.sty
Package: scrlayer-scrpage 2023/04/24 v3.40 KOMA-Script package (end user interf
ace for scrlayer)

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/koma-script\scr
layer.sty
Package: scrlayer 2023/04/24 v3.40 KOMA-Script package (defining layers and pag
e styles)
Package scrlayer Info: patching LaTeX kernel macro \pagestyle on input line 217
6.
)
Package scrlayer-scrpage Info: Makeing stand-alone element `pagehead' from
(scrlayer-scrpage)             alias to `pageheadfoot' on input line 1097.
)
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lm\lmodern.sty
Package: lmodern 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Latin Modern Fonts
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/lmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/lmm/m/it on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/lmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/lmm/b/it on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/lmsy/b/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/lmss/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/lmr/m/it on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/lmss/bx/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/lmr/bx/it on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 38.
) (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/mwe\mwe.sty
Package: mwe 2018/03/30 v0.5 Package to support minimal working examples (MWE)

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphi
cx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphi
cs.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.s
ty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\gr
aphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pd
ftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen142
\Gin@req@width=\dimen143
)
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lipsum\lipsum.s
ty
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3packages/l3ke
ys2e\l3keys2e.sty
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.
sty
Package: expl3 2023-05-11 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3bac
kend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2023-04-19 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count197
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box53
))
Package: l3keys2e 2023-02-02 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
Package: lipsum 2021-09-20 v2.7 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
\g__lipsum_par_int=\count198
\l__lipsum_a_int=\count199
\l__lipsum_b_int=\count266

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lipsum\lipsum.l
td.tex))
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/blindtext\blind
text.sty
Package: blindtext 2012/01/06 V2.0 blindtext-Package

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tools\xspace.st
y
Package: xspace 2014/10/28 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
)
\c@blindtext=\count267
\c@Blindtext=\count268
\c@blind@countparstart=\count269
\blind@countxx=\count270
\blindtext@numBlindtext=\count271
\blind@countyy=\count272
\c@blindlist=\count273
\c@blindlistlevel=\count274
\c@blindlist@level=\count275
\blind@listitem=\count276
\c@blind@listcount=\count277
\c@blind@levelcount=\count278
\blind@mathformula=\count279
\blind@Mathformula=\count280
\c@blind@randomcount=\count281
\c@blind@randommax=\count282
\c@blind@pangramcount=\count283
\c@blind@pangrammax=\count284
))
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperr
ef.sty
Package: hyperref 2023-04-22 v7.00x Hypertext links for LaTeX

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcm
ds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.s
ty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pd
ftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/infwarerr\inf
warerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/kvsetkeys\kvset
keys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2022-10-05 v1.19 Key value parser (HO)
)
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/kvdefinekeys\
kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdfescape\pdf
escape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
)
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hycolor\hycolor
.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/letltxmacro\let
ltxmacro.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
)
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/auxhook\auxhook
.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\namere
f.sty
Package: nameref 2022-05-17 v2.50 Cross-referencing by name of section

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/refcount\refcou
nt.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/gettitlestrin
g\gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvopt
ions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2022-06-15 v3.15 Key value format for package options (HO)
))
\c@section@level=\count285
)
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolb
ox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count286
)
\@linkdim=\dimen144
\Hy@linkcounter=\count287
\Hy@pagecounter=\count288

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc
.def
File: pd1enc.def 2023-04-22 v7.00x Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
)
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/intcalc\intca
lc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count289

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\puenc.
def
File: puenc.def 2023-04-22 v7.00x Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `colorlinks' set `true' on input line 4065.
Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarksnumbered' set `true' on input line 4065
.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4182.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4187.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4190.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4197.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4202.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4449.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count290

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/url\url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4787.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen145

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/bitset\bitset
.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/bigintcalc\bi
gintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count291
\Field@Width=\dimen146
\Fld@charsize=\dimen147
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6066.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6071.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6074.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6081.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring ON on input line 6084.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6091.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6096.

(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\atbegshi-l
tx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count292
\c@Item=\count293
\c@Hfootnote=\count294
)
! Extra \else.
\Hy@AtEndOfPackageHook ...color}\fi \fi \fi \else 
                                                  \def \HyOpt@DriverType { (...
l.12 \usepackage
                [noabbrev, nameinlink]{cleveref}
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

! Extra \fi.
\Hy@AtEndOfPackageHook ...\HyOpt@CustomDriver \fi 
                                                  \Hy@InfoNoLine {Driver\HyO...
l.12 \usepackage
                [noabbrev, nameinlink]{cleveref}
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

Package hyperref Info: Driver (custom): .

! LaTeX Error: File `.def' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: def)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.12 \usepackage
                [noabbrev, nameinlink]{cleveref}^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 13894 strings out of 476360
 279425 string characters out of 5784213
 1853993 words of memory out of 5000000
 34194 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 513356 words of font info for 34 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 108i,1n,106p,10913b,270s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced
```

!

Comment: it runs without error in texlive, make a more reasonable example, delete every package you can delete while still showing the problem, then see if you can update the package causing the problem.

Comment: also, show the full error from the log file (texstudio's "summary" is not usable for debugging)

Comment: Unrelated (probably): you load the `color` package as well as the newer `xcolor` package, I would guess that loading the latter is enough. Also, `pgfplots` loads `tikz` already, so there is no need to load `tikz` separately.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle is this valid LaTeX, `\usepackage[numbers, square, sort&compress, super]{natbib}`? I have never seen an ampersand used in package options before, was going to ask a new question (maybe I should as I haven't been able to find a reference for it) but thought I'd ping first if it was trivial/obvious

Comment: @JamesT yes that is an option, see natbib.sty: `\DeclareOption{sort&compress}{\def\NAT@sort{\@ne}\def\NAT@cmprs{\@ne}}`

Comment: The example runs in TL23,22,21,20,19. Did you remember to update miktex in miktex usermode and in miktex admin mode (if availalble)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, it seems like this package is the problem:
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, filecolor=cyan, urlcolor=cyan, bookmarksnumbered=true]{hyperref}

Is the hyperref package outdated for the newer versions?

Comment: @FantasticMsFox Please show you complete .log file. Maybe you locally have an outdated version installed. Also did you already try to delete all the auxiliary files and recompile from scratch?

Comment: hyperref is maintained by the core latex team and works in the example here. If you provide a reasonable example and show your  log someone will be able to say what is wrong on your system, don't ask people to trace the loading of gigantic packages like tikz if you see the same error wthout that

Comment: show the full log not a fragment without the main information such as location and version of the package. But first make a more reasonable example so the log is smaller

Comment: Thanks David - you´re right. This is my first time using Latex and this forum. I thought maybe it´ll be easier to see all packages in case two or more don´t work when used together. I´ll do better next time :-)

Comment: I also do not get an error message. The differences in package versions are, that I have expl3 2023-05-15 instead of 2023-05-11 and iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f instead of 2020/03/06 v1.0d. LaTeX version and L3 programming layer are the same. [MiKTeX also provides iftex v1.0f](https://miktex.org/packages/iftex) and [AFAIK l3kernel 2023-05-15, which provides expl3](https://miktex.org/packages/l3kernel). So it seems not all of your packages are up-to-date.

Comment: I will  try on MiKTeX later.

Comment: I checked on MiKTeX, as far as I see, all packages are up to date (today).

Comment: @FantasticMsFox On my machine MiKTeX has `iftex` v1.0f, yours is v1.0d as cabohah mentions. Just copied v1.0d into my local directory and indeed that seems to be the problem. Not sure about this but some people need to update packages in both "Admin" and "User" mode

Comment: as @mbert wrote: you have an outdated iftex, try to deinstall and reinstall that.

Comment: MikTex didn´t show that any update was necessary but when I deleted iftex from my computer and reinstalled it, it finally worked. THANK YOU